# Как найти одинаковые элементы массива в С?

Tags: c, массивы

Как написать нахождение двух одинаковых элементов в массиве. Напишете пожайлуста с комментариями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++) { // цикл по первому элементу
  for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++) { // цикл по второму элементу
    if (a[i] == a[j]) { // ищем одинаковые
      printf("a[%d] == a[%d] == %d\n", i, j, a[i]); // сообщим пользователю об этом
    }
  }
}
```

осталось мелочи поправить и можно сдавать преподавателю.